# My domain name is in the public_html directory - opencart

Tags: opencart, public-html

I had my domain name transferred from Namecheap to my hosting provider, but I now have it show up in the public_html folder. How do I place it so I can have it point correctly to my opencart store?

Answer (score 0):

Part of it, your hoster will do for you, and the rest you do. Say you have put your store in a `shop` subdirectory, and the path to that folder is

/home/martin/public_html/shop/

Your hoster will ensure that http://www.your-domain.com points to `/home/martin/public_html/`.

Then you will need to update your `config.php` and `admin/config.php` files point `HTTP_SERVER` and `HTTPS_SERVER` to point to `http[s]://www.your-domain.com/shop`.

Then your store will be online as http://www.your-domain.com/shop.

Comment: Thanks. So I changed both config.php and admin/config.php but my url shows up as a subdomain of public_html:                    
          public_html/www.your-domain.com.  I am using a free hosting service so I don't get support from them. How do I point it myself in cpanel to the right place? Thanks.

Comment: If you're running a business, you shouldn't be using free hosting. :)